# OpenGL VBO's in Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell, vertex-array, vertex-array-object

Basing on [this post](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-August/046514.html), I was trying to figure out how to use VBO's in Haskell. I tried to fill in the bits that were not covered there:

```
data Sprite = Sprite { spriteImage :: Image
                     , spritePosition :: Position
                     } deriving (Show, Eq)

spriteBatch :: [Sprite] -> [(TextureObject, [Sprite])]
spriteBatch = (map f) . toList . (groupedBy (imageTexture . spriteImage))
    where f (t, s) = (t, s)

offset = plusPtr nullPtr

renderSprites :: [Sprite] -> IO ()
renderSprites l = (flip mapM_) (spriteBatch l) $ \(t, sps) -> do
        textureBinding Texture2D $= Just t
        let l = concat $ map sprToList sps
        vbo <- vboOfList ((length l)*4) l
        displayVbo vbo $ fromIntegral $ length sps
    where
        sprToList :: Sprite -> [GLfloat]
        sprToList (Sprite (Image _ (TexCoord2 u0 v0) (TexCoord2 u1 v1) (Size w h) _) (Position x y)) = 
            [fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, u0, v0
            ,fromIntegral (x+w), fromIntegral y, u1, v0
            ,fromIntegral (x+w), fromIntegral (y+h), u1, v1
            ,fromIntegral x, fromIntegral (y+h), u0, v1
            ]

vboOfList :: Int -> [GLfloat] -> IO BufferObject
vboOfList size elems = do
    let ptrsize = toEnum $ size * 4
        arrayType = ElementArrayBuffer
    (array:_) <- genObjectNames 1
    bindBuffer arrayType $= Just array
    arr <- newListArray (0, size - 1) elems
    withStorableArray arr $ \ptr -> bufferData arrayType $= (ptrsize, ptr, StaticDraw)
    bindBuffer ArrayBuffer $= Nothing
    return array

displayVbo buff size = do
    let stride = 2*(2*4)
        vxDesc = VertexArrayDescriptor 2 Float stride $ offset 0
        texCoo = VertexArrayDescriptor 2 Float stride $ offset 8
    bindBuffer ArrayBuffer $= Just buff

    arrayPointer VertexArray $= vxDesc
    arrayPointer TextureCoordArray $= texCoo

    clientState VertexArray $= Enabled
    clientState TextureCoordArray $= Enabled

    drawArrays Quads 0 size
    bindBuffer ArrayBuffer $= Nothing
```

You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/scan/Colin/blob/vbo/src/Colin/Sprite.hs), in case you need to.

On the [master branch](https://github.com/scan/Colin/blob/master/src/Colin/Sprite.hs), the very same function uses normal `vertex` calls to draw the `Sprites` and it works perfectly. But using VBO's, the sprite just isn't there; I get a blank screen.

Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong here?

Comment: Could you explain to us what is wrong in the first place?  Does it compile and misbehave?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Oh yes, sorry. It compiles perfectly, but the screen remains blank. The sprite doesn't show up - and it has to be in the VBO part above because the same without VBO works well.

Answer (score 1):

You're using one buffer for vertices and uvs. Use two buffers, one for vertices and one for uvs.